# PHP 5.4 extensions enabled by default

Tags: php, compilation, installation

I'm trying to find a list of the extensions enabled by default in PHP 5.4. I have found the list of [configuration options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php).

However, short of installing PHP 5.4 with the following, I'd like to know what is enabled by default.

```
./configure
make
make install
php -i
```

This should documented somewhere... does anyone know where?

Comment: You could always get the default php.ini file and parse out the enabled extension directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there is a way to do this pre-build. This is 5.4.12 without any options to configure on OS X:

```
php-5.4.12 matthew$ sapi/cli/php -m

[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
```

Note that you don't have to `make install`. Simply:

```
./configure
make
sapi/cli/php -m
```

Comment: PHP analyzes your previous configuration. Compare this against `php -m` to ensure it's truly the defaults.

Comment: I confirmed this myself. These are indeed the defaults. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at below site:

[compile-options-configuration-php-5-4-5](http://www.synet.sk/php/en/192-compile-options-configuration-php-5-4-5)

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Comment: This is an output of `./configure --help`. Although it does show default values, it does not show which extensions are enabled by default.